# Percents on top of stacked bar graph R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to create a stacked bar graph in `ggplot2` with percent shares on top of them. After looking at many other posts, I couldn't figure out a solution, so here are some sample data:

```
# load some libraries
library(ggplot2)

# make basic data frame
df <- data.frame(type = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 year = c(2001,2002, 2001, 2002),
                 count_A = c(3, 2, NA, NA),
                 count_B = c(NA, NA, 8, 1),
                 sum_year_AB =  c(11,3,11,3),
                 total_count_with_irrelevant_types = c(13,14,19,23))

# create single percentage variable for top of bar
df$percent_AB_year = (df$sum_year_AB/df$total_count_with_irrelevant_types)*100
df$percent_AB_year = round(df$percent_AB, 1)
df$percent_final = paste0(df$percent_AB_year, "%")
df$percent_AB_year = ifelse(df$type=="B", NA, df$percent_AB_year)
df$percent_final = ifelse(df$type=="B", NA, df$percent_final)
```

[image]

Here is my code for the bar graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=type, x=year, y=sum_year_AB)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = .9) +
  labs(fill="Type",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Count",
       title = "Count by Year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1999,2003,1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = percent_final), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .6)
```

And here is the output of the graph:
[image]

How do I put the percents on top?

Comment: Put position = "stack" in the geom_text call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position = "stack"` inside `geom_text` too:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(fill=type, x=year, y=sum_year_AB)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = .9) +
  labs(fill="Type",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Count",
       title = "Count by Year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1999,2003,1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = percent_final), size = 3, position = "stack", vjust = -0.2) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion, I would include it in the bar plot rather than placing it at the top (because the other `percent_final` values in your `df` are `NA`).

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(df, aes(fill=type, x=year, y=sum_year_AB)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = .9) +
  labs(fill="Type",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Count",
       title = "Count by Year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1999,2003,1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = percent_final),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="blue", size = 9) +
  theme_economist()
```

plot:

[image]